# Preparing a Latex submission to a journal via Editorial Manager

Tags: bibtex, lyx, journal-publishing

I'm attempting to submit a paper written in Lyx (references using `bibtex`) to a journal that uses Editorial Manager (I'm a total novice here). The journal has instructions for submitting Tex submission files but asks for the following files that I have no idea how to generate or locate: 
`testtex.tex` (as manuscript item)
`testclo.clo` (as manuscript item)
`testclass.cls` (as manuscript item)
`teststyle.sty` (as manuscript item)
`testbest.bst` (as manuscript item)

Does anyone know how to find/generate these files? I realize that some are `bibtex` (rather than TeX) files but I'm not sure how to get these either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I sure hope you are not working against a tight deadline ;) I suppose you have the paper exported from LyX to LaTeX format? That should give you the `.tex` file. You will likely have to hand-edit that in order to conform to the publisher's rules. I would assume that the `.cls`, `.clo` and `.mst` files should be provided by the the publisher. It would help if you could name the publisher and provide a link to the page with their LaTeX-specific instructions.

Comment: Right. I can get the tex files like you described and the answer below helped me to find some of the others. The journal is run by Springer but the only instructions I can find are from Editorial Manager itself (https://www.editorialmanager.com/robohelp/10.1/EM_Knowledge_Base/Preparing_of_a_Tex_Submission_for_Editorial_Manager.htm)

Here's the relevant section
"We suggest Uploading the TeX Submission files in the following order:
-     testtex.tex 
-     testclo.clo 
-     testclass.cls 
-     teststyle.sty 
-     testbest.bst"

Answer (score 3):

Starting with LyX 2.2.0, the file in-between a .lyx file and the output .pdf file are more accessible. To get all of the files, do the following:

1. View the document (e.g. click on the eyes icon).
2. Go back to LyX and go to Document > LaTeX Log.
3. In that dialog, click on the "Open Containing Directory" button.

A directory will pop up with all files that were used to create the PDF.

If you happen to be using Linux, these files can alternatively be located by just navigating to the folder /tmp/lyx_tmpdir*/lyx_tmpbuf0 or something like that. I'm not sure how it works on Mac or Windows.

Comment: This is really helpful. I was able to find most of what I need in this way. Even here, though, not all of the files the journal asks for are listed. I'm still not able to find the testclo.clo,  testclass.cls, and teststyle.sty.

Comment: I suspect that these are just dummy names; but the explanations on that page clearly fall short. As a first attempt, I would simply omit them and see if that goes through. If it doesn't, see what error messages you get, and if those don't make sense, call their supporrrt center.